# Error Unable to authenticate, need: BASIC realm="Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager" while upgrating Angular from 11 to 12

Tags: angular, angular-upgrade

**My current version is**: 11.2.3

**The error is**: An unhandled exception occurred: Unable to authenticate, need: BASIC realm="Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager"

I have updated my project from later versions, and have never had an update problem.

I attach some libraries from my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.2.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~11.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.3",
    "@angular/core": "~11.2.3",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.2.3",
    "@angular/material": "^11.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.3",
    "@angular/router": "~11.2.3",
    "@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet": "^8.1.0",
    "@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet-draw": "^7.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^9.0.2",
    "angular-highcharts": "^11.3.1",
    "highcharts": "^9.0.1",
    "leaflet": "^1.7.1",
    "leaflet-draw": "^1.0.4",
    "leaflet-easybutton": "^2.4.0",
    "leaflet.markercluster": "^1.4.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1102.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.2.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/leaflet": "^1.5.23",
    "@types/leaflet-draw": "^1.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.1.2"
  }
```

the complete error as:

```
[error] HttpErrorAuthUnknown: Unable to authenticate, need: BASIC realm="Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager"
    at C:\Users\juanj\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\npm-registry-fetch\check-response.js:124:17
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async Object.fetchPackageManifest (C:\Users\juanj\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\utilities\package-metadata.js:173:22)
    at async UpdateCommand.checkCLILatestVersion (C:\Users\juanj\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\update-impl.js:638:35)
    at async UpdateCommand.run (C:\Users\juanj\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\update-impl.js:198:38)
    at async UpdateCommand.validateAndRun (C:\Users\juanj\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command.js:136:22)
    at async Object.runCommand (C:\Users\juanj\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js:205:24)
    at async default_1 (C:\Users\juanj\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js:70:31)
```